# Combine names of a Subfolder within a Subfolder to make a String

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I'm trying to get achieve creating a new **string** which is a combination of a **folder path** with a **subfolder** in VBA Excel 2007.

Is there a way I can combine CurDir() with folder.path and path.separators which will give the result of a combined string?

Example:

```
\\Tardis\Data\[PATH] = ParentPath
\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\HELLO = 1st Subfolder
\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\HELLO\WORLD = 2nd Subfolder
```

Result:
HELLO WORLD

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your problem is. "print" where? Typically you use "&" to concatenate strings in VBA, and you can use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of "\" if you need your code to work on Macs also.

Comment: If you mean you're trying to print a string that combines the folder names into a sentence, separated by spaces instead of path separators, you can use the `Split` and `Join` VBA String functions with the info @TimWilliams provided.

Comment: @Blackhawk is there an example you're able to give using `Split` and `Join` in VBA with a folder path? Also I've clarified my wording in the question.

Comment: I've reread your question and I'm skind of confused.  You have a CurrDir() = `\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\HELLO\WORLD` and you want to remove the left side `\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\` and replace the `/` in the rest with spaces??? `HELLO WORLD`  If not, can you clarify?

Comment: +1 for having a Tardis root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a SWAG at this: I think you want to create a string that combines the directory and sub-directory names with a space in between.

Here is a script that assumes more than one subfolder in your current directory and uses `FileSystemObject` and `Folder` to create a name as you describe for each one (held in and accessible from an array). NOTE that you need to set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. I tested this with a file path to My Documents on my C: drive and it worked. Hope this helps:

```
Sub CreateStringsForSubfolders()

    'To use this you need a reference set for Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    '~~>dim variables and set initial values
        Dim fsObject As New FileSystemObject
        Dim fFolder As Folder
            Set fFolder = fsObject.GetFolder("\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\HELLO")
        Dim fSubfolder As Folder
        Dim aNames() As String
            ReDim aNames(1) As String

    '~~>loop to create name for each subfolder
        For Each fSubfolder In fFolder.SubFolders
            ReDim Preserve aNames(UBound(aNames) + 1)
            aNames(UBound(aNames)) = fFolder.Name & " " & fSubfolder.Name
            Debug.Print aNames(UBound(aNames)) 'press [CTRL + G] to see the names created
        Next

End Sub
```

---

Here is a modified code with your requirement. I'm not really sure what you're doing with this (it might have helped if you had included that information in your question) so I assumed that you just wanted to add the sub folders to the array.  If you actually wanted there always to be two folders' names in the string created, then use the commented alternative in the `Else` section.

```
Sub CreateStringsForSubfolders2()

    '~~>dim variables and set initial values
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim fsObject As New FileSystemObject
        Dim fFolder As Folder
            Set fFolder = fsObject.GetFolder("\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]")
        Dim fSubfolder As Folder
        Dim fSubfolder2 As Folder
        Dim aNames() As String
            ReDim aNames(1) As String

    '~~>loop to create name for each subfolder and any sub-subfolders
        For Each fSubfolder In fFolder.SubFolders
            ReDim Preserve aNames(UBound(aNames) + 1)
            sPath = fSubfolder.Path
            Set fSubfolder = fsObject.GetFolder(sPath)
            If fSubfolder.SubFolders.Count <> 0 Then
                For Each fSubfolder2 In fSubfolder.SubFolders
                    ReDim Preserve aNames(UBound(aNames) + 1)
                    aNames(UBound(aNames)) = fSubfolder.Name & " " & _
                                                        fSubfolder2.Name
                    Debug.Print aNames(UBound(aNames))
                Next fSubfolder2
            Else
                aNames(UBound(aNames)) = fSubfolder.Name 
                                         'or fFolder.Name & " " fSubfolder.Name
                Debug.Print aNames(UBound(aNames))
            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! However, the issues starts to arise since there are two sub-directories that it has to look into and I am unsure how to add another 'layer' to your above code - but in other words your way works!

Comment: Julz, to solve the issue you described in your edit, you just need to nest another loop inside the first one. Because some of the sub-folders for my original path did not have sub-subfolders I made the loop conditional (only employs the second loop if there is another level present).  Hope this helps.  Also: your question was not very clear. You might want to [READ THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before posting your next question.

Answer (score 0):

This code was kindly provided for this solution although I sometimes get a User-defined type not defined error - can anyone tell me why?

```
Sub ListFiles()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String

    'Assign the top folder to a variable
    strTopFolderName = "\\Tardis\Data\[PATH]\"

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

    'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder)

End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objSubFolder2 As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim myString As String

    myString = ""

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        For Each objSubFolder2 In objSubFolder.SubFolders
            If myString = "" Then
                myString = objSubFolder2.Name
            Else
                myString = objSubFolder.Name & " " & objSubFolder2.Name
                Debug.Print myString
            End If
        Next objSubFolder2

        myString = ""

    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: What part of the code is highlighted by VBA when you get that error?  Which piece of code does it point to as the "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: @Blackhawk `Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder)` this part

Comment: The only reason it might do that is if you copy this code into a new excel document without adding a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  You would do that by going into the VBA window, clicking Tools ---> References... and checking the box next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".